# If Else in R, if product ID is X then change Product Name

Tags: r, if-statement, replace

I am trying to figure out what is working and why the other way is not working for me.

At the moment I have a list of shops I use and I need to change the naming every time; so I have decided to go by the `product_id` which never changes, but my code is not working.

`product_id <- vector()`

This one is not working:

```
product_name[product_id == '40600000003'] <- 'my cool store']
```

but this one does work:

```
product_name[product_name == 'my#cool@Store'] <- 'my cool store'
```

Now, I am not sure what am I doing wrong, I tried to do:

```
if (product_id == '40600000003') {
      product_name = 'my cool shop'
}
```

I have a list of 15 shops that I need to change the naming as they arrive in the wrong format from the api connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try 40600000003 instead of '40600000003' it's more than likely reading your vector slots as int if it doesn't contain any characters

Comment: In if (product_id == 40600000003) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: I meant without the loop...also..if this is a find and replace scenario look at vapply.  Just go to ?vapply and look at "replace"

Comment: Excuse me..without the "if" not "loop"